# Android : How to put geopoint in to Bundle in onSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm on the way of developing application using Google Map API,
I *draw the path of two points (`GeoPoint`) successful*.

And when changing from portrait to landscape, 
The *map will invalidate* (because of activity life-cycle), you know?
So, I *lost two that points*.

I know we must save two that points in method **`onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState)`**.
Therefore, I **want to save two that point** (`GeoPoint`) for draw again when changing from portrait to landscape.

I don't know **how to put `GeoPoint` into that `Bundle` in that method**.
Please tell me?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint) tells me `Geopoint` has a constuctor with two params: latitude, longitude. Both attributes have getters. So either you obtain those and put them in the `Bundle`, or you extend the class and [make it parcellable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable), or make a wrapper class. Either solution will work just fine.

Try this, I suspect it'll work just fine.

```
public class ParcelableGeoPoint implements Parcelable {
    private GeoPoint point;    

    public ParcelableGeoPoint(int lat, int lon){
        point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
    }

    public ParcelableGeoPoint(Parcel in){
        int[] data = new int[2];
        in.readIntArray(data);
        point = new GeoPoint(data[0], data[1]);
    }

    public int describeContents(){
        return 0;
    }

    public GeoPoint unwrap() {
        return point;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeIntArray(new int[] {point.getLat(), point.getLon()});
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public ParcelableGeoPoint createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ParcelableGeoPoint(in); 
        }

        public ParcelableGeoPoint[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ParcelableGeoPoint[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Then, put it in your `Bundle` with `bundle.putParcelable("MYPOINT", geopointParcelable)`